# Scroll window to current line of contenteditable block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a very simple form with sticky footer

```
<div contenteditable>Start typing ...</div>

<div class="sticky-footer">
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaNgQV

And when text reaches footer, it goes under it

So I am searching for a simple solution to auto scroll window if some content is overlapped while typing

**EDIT**

I guess it is not a problem if `contenteditable` div has its own scroll bar, but is there a solution for global scrollbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```
const el = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]')
el.addEventListener('keyup', ({target: {lastChild}}) => lastChild.scrollIntoView())
```

https://codepen.io/wintercounter/pen/pZjeLW

Contenteditable is creating `div`s for every linebreak. We're simply scrolling to the last child of the whole editable area.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use  `style="overflow: scroll";` on `<div contenteditable>Start typing ...</div>`

```
<div contenteditable style="overflow: scroll";>Start typing ...</div>

<div class="sticky-footer">
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I here made some changes in your code.

[Click Here To See](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpbBLB)

```
<div contenteditable class="editableContent">Start typing ...</div>

<div class="sticky-footer">
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>


.sticky-footer {
 position:sticky;
 bottom:0;
 padding:20px 0;
 background:#eee
 }

 .editableContent{

  min-height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add this code in the pen:

```
div[contenteditable]{
  height:calc(100vh - 70px);
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the working example of the code:

```css
.sticky-footer {
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:#eee
}
div[contenteditable]{
  height:calc(100vh - 70px);
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div contenteditable>Start typing ...</div>
<div class="sticky-footer">
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `overflow: auto` by setting the `max-height` of the editable content container by calculating the view port height minus the height of the sticky footer. Please check the working example below:

```css
.sticky-footer {
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:#eee
}
.content-editable{
  min-height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 65px);
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable class="content-editable">Start typing ...</div>
<div class="sticky-footer">
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```